# RegEx targeted replace with Named Captures

Tags: regex, powershell

Given

```
$line = '{initError-[cf][3]}_Invalid nodes(s): [3]'
```

I can use

```
$line -match '^\{(?<type>[a-z]+)(-\[(?<target>(C|F|CF))\])?(\[(?<tab>\d+)\])?\}_(?<string>.*)'
```

And `$matches['tab']` will correctly have a value of 3. However, if I then want to increment that value, without also affecting the [3] in the string section things get more complicated. I can use `$tabIndex = $line.indexOf("[$tab]")` to get the index of the first occurrence, and I can also use `$newLine = ([regex]"\[$tab\]").Replace($line, '[4]', 1)` to only replace the first occurrence. But I wonder, is there a way to get at the this more directly? It's not strictly necessary, as I will only ever want to replace things within the initial {}_, which has a very consistent form, so replacing first instance works, just wondering if I am missing out on a more elegant solution, which also might be needed in a different situation.

Comment: Do you just want to increment all numbers in square brackets? Note you can't replace a group directly, they are meant to extract text, not for replacing. You usually capture what you need to *keep*, and just *match* what you need to *remove*.

Comment: Try  `$callback = {  param($m) '[' + ([convert]::ToInt32($m.Groups[1].Value, 10) + 1) + ']' }` => `$regex=[regex]'\[(\d+)]'` => `$regex.Replace($line, $callback)`

Answer (score 0):

I would change the regex a bit, because mixing Named captures with Numbered captures is not recommended, so it becomes this:

```
'^\{(?<type>[a-z]+)(?:-\[(?<target>[CF]{1,2})\])?(?:\[(?<tab>\d+)\])?\}_(?<string>.*)'
```

You could then use it like below to replace the `tab` value:

```
$line        = '{initError-[cf][3]}_Invalid nodes(s): [3]'
$newTabValue = 12345

$line -replace '^\{(?<type>[a-z]+)(?:-\[(?<target>[CF]{1,2})\])?(?:\[(?<tab>\d+)\])?\}_(?<string>.*)', "{`${type}-[`${target}][$newTabValue]}_`${string}"
```

The result of this will be:

> `{initError-[cf][12345]}_Invalid nodes(s): [3]`

Regex details:

```
^                    Assert position at the beginning of the string
\{                   Match the character “{” literally
(?<type>             Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “type”
   [a-z]             Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z”
      +              Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
(?:                  Match the regular expression below
   -                 Match the character “-” literally
   \[                Match the character “[” literally
   (?<target>        Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “target”
      [CF]           Match a single character present in the list “CF”
         {1,2}       Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   )
   \]                Match the character “]” literally
)?                   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?:                  Match the regular expression below
   \[                Match the character “[” literally
   (?<tab>           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “tab”
      \d             Match a single digit 0..9
         +           Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   )
   \]                Match the character “]” literally
)?                   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\}                   Match the character “}” literally
_                    Match the character “_” literally
(?<string>           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “string”
   .                 Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *              Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of increasing the first number in the brackets is using the `-Split` operator to access the number you want to change:

```
$line = '{initError-[cf][3]}_Invalid nodes(s): [3]'
$NewLine = $line -split "(\d+)"
$NewLine[1] = [int]$newLine[1] + 1
-join $NewLine
```

Output:

```
{initError-[cf][4]}_Invalid nodes(s): [3]
```